# Visual Studio Code debugs python 2.7 app in a docker container with python3

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to debug my app in a docker container. The app is written in paython 2.7 but VS Code tries to debug it with python 3. Therfore, it cannot resolve packages and throws execptions.

Any idea?

My configurataions:

tasks.json

```
    {
      "version": "2.0.0",
      "tasks": [
        {
          "type": "docker-run",
          "label": "docker-run: debug",
          "dependsOn": ["docker-build"],
          "dockerRun": {
            "containerName": "account",
            "image": "account:latest",
            "env": {},
            "volumes": [
              {
                "containerPath": "/code",
                "localPath": "${workspaceFolder}"
              }
            ],
            "ports": [
              {
                "containerPort": 8086,
                "hostPort": 8086
              },
              {
                "containerPort": 8085,
                "hostPort": 8085
              }
            ]
          },
          "python": {
            "args": ["--config=/code/config/account.conf.localstage"],
            "file": "skoobe-accountd"
          }
        },
        {
          "label": "docker-build",
          "type": "docker-build",
          "dockerBuild": {
              "context": "${workspaceFolder}",
              "dockerfile": "${workspaceFolder}/Dockerfile.arm.dev",
              "tag": "account:latest"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

launch.json

```
    {
      "configurations": [
        {
          "name": "Debug Account",
          "type": "docker",
          "request": "launch",
          "preLaunchTask": "docker-run: debug",
          "python": {
            "pathMappings": [
              {
                "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
                "remoteRoot": "/code"
              }
            ],
            "projectType": "general"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

settings.json

```
    {
        "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
        "python.pythonPath": "/usr/bin/python"
    }
```

Dockerfile

```
    FROM python:2.7.18

    ENV AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="xxx"
    ENV AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="xxx"
    ENV AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="xxx"
    ENV SQS_QUEUE="xxx"
    ENV SQS_CHANGE_QUEUE="xxx"


    # RUN mkdir -p /root/.ssh && \
    #    chmod 0700 /root/.ssh


    # RUN apt-get update && \
    #    apt-get install openssh-server -y

    WORKDIR /code/
    ADD requirements.txt /code/
    RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

    ADD . /code/

    WORKDIR tools/
    RUN python setup.py install
    WORKDIR /code/
    # RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

    CMD ["python", "accountd", "--config=/code/config/account.conf.localstage"]
```

Comment: Show us your Dockerfile!

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution after some investigation:

I modfied `lunch.json` to the following:

```
    {
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [
          {
            "name": "Python: Remote Attach",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 5678,
            "host": "localhost",
            "pathMappings": [
                {
                    "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
                    "remoteRoot": "/code"
                }
            ]
          }
        ]
    }
```

Then I added the following lines into the entypoint Python file:

```
import ptvsd
ptvsd.enable_attach(address=('0.0.0.0', 5678))
```

After running the docker container, from VS code IDE, I could run in debug mode.